# How to parse factor/dataframe with Rembedded

Tags: c, r

I am in the process of writing an api that will convert the native SEXP objects to protocol buffers so that I can serialize them. My problem arises when trying to convert a SEXP object from a dataframe using recursive function. The issue is when I find an INTSXP that inherits factor; the factor only sees two levels in the level count. Is there an example somewhere about how to handle a factor in c? Or does someone have advice atleast on why I am only seeing two levels. Also I have a feeling I am going to run into another issue when handling the NA but haven't tried handling that yet.

I am guessing the issue is some internal feature of R is seeing red twice and just creating a pointer when creating the dataframe.

**R Version**

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

**CODE**

Here is the R code that I am executing. It is running through a jni interface and getting back a protocol buffer.

```
String command = "d <- c(1,2,3,4); e <- c(\"red\", \"white\", \"red\", NA); f <- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE); mydata <- data.frame(d,e,f);";
```

Here is where I am handling the types.

```
case INTSXP: // #define INTSXP      13    /* integer vectors */
        // factors have internal type INTSXP too
        if (Rf_inherits(model, "factor")) {
            int levelCount = Rf_nlevels(model);
            if (levelCount > 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Got a factor with count %d\n", levelCount);
                SEXP levels = Rf_getAttrib(model, Rf_install("levels"));
                fill_rexp(rexp, levels);
            }
            break;
        }

        rexp->rclass = REXP__RCLASS__INTSXP;
        rexp->n_intvalue = LENGTH(model);
        rexp->intvalue = malloc(sizeof(rexp->intvalue) * (rexp->n_intvalue));
        for (i = 0; i < rexp->n_intvalue; i++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Setting value of rexp to %d %d\n",i,  (INTEGER(model)[i]));
            rexp->intvalue[0] = (INTEGER(model)[i]);
        }

        break;
    case REALSXP: //#define REALSXP     14    /* real variables */
        rexp->rclass = REXP__RCLASS__REALSXP;
```

Notice in the output that the "Got a factor with count 2" is that I thought would be 4. Is there a cleaner way to handle this in c?

```
Type of model is 19
Size of vector is 3
Type of model is 14
Setting value of rexp to 0 1.000000
Setting value of rexp to 1 2.000000
Setting value of rexp to 2 3.000000
Setting value of rexp to 3 4.000000
Type of model is 13
Got a factor with count 2
Type of model is 16
Number of strings 2
Type of model is 10
Count of children in vector 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're converting a factor to character, you want `Rf_asCharacterFactor`.

Comment: THIS COULD HAVE BEEN BROUGHT TO MY ATTENTION YESTERDAY!!!! :) Thanks for that tip. This is the correct solution. Thanks Kevin

Comment: I wish there was better documentation on what all the Rf_ functions do, this could have been solved much easier had there been some kind of api doc that I could find. Are these documented anywhere?

Comment: Not really :/ There's documentation scattered throughout [R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) and [R-ints](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html), but for finding the available functions it pays to just read `Rinternals.h`, and also read some of the R source code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works!! I found the example in the Rcpp. I tried the Rf_coerce to see if that was working in R-3.0.2 but when I tried to coerce it to STRSXP it returned me integers. So I used the example code below to get this to return me the values from the factor.

```
case INTSXP:
    {
    // return Rf_coerceVector( x, STRSXP );
    // coerceVector does not work for some reason
    SEXP call = PROTECT( Rf_lang2( Rf_install( "as.character" ), x ) ) ;
    SEXP res  = PROTECT( Rf_eval( call, R_GlobalEnv ) ) ;
    UNPROTECT(2);
```

BTW in the future I would have just spent some time learning cpp better and used Rcpp but my experience with cpp is lacking.